# Show information into div with ajax setTiemout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have another doubt about Ajax and Jquery I need to append the code I recieve correctly since database , but when I put the code into div #datos the code repeat everytime , I don't need that code was repeat everytime.

```
setInterval(function() {                  
        $.ajax({
            async:true,
           type: "GET",
           url:"obtenercomentarios",
           success:obtener,
           timeout:4000
       });
         }, 1000);


function obtener(response){
    $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
      $( "#datos" ).append(value.emisor);
      $( "#datos" ).append(value.contenido);

    });
}
```

An image is better than 1000 words in this case

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. With setInterval() you are getting the data through ajax every 1000ms, that's why you the response is written multiple times.

Comment: Ok ,  I need to update the information in two clients at the same time for this reason I reload setInterval every second.

Comment: Just `empty()` the element before appending the update. Append will add to the existing content when what you want is to refresh it. Compare if the content differ and only update it if it has changed would be better performance wise too.

Comment: Websocket would be a lot better for this. Here this way in theory you should track the order of the query too as here depending on the time the query take there is room for previous data to be displayed after more recent one. Websocket will give you the advantage of only being triggered if the data is actually updated.

Comment: @gillesc  I know that websocket is better for this , but the exam today require this tipe of code , inclusive I am learning NodeJS for this cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Don't use `.append()` use `.html()` instead, or if you want the divs to have some static text before the appended text just use a `span` inside the divs right after the static text and use `.html()`, that case every time the code get executed, the span contents will be replaced with the new contents.
Example:

```
<div id="datos">
Hi there <span id="mySpan"></span>
</div>

$( "#mySpan" ).html(value.emisor);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I always confused .append with .html  , I supose in another case I don't have any mistakes with this.